# Twitter Bootstrap - unusual arrangement of the columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem and I can't find a good solution right now. What I want to achieve is this (on screen size >= medium):

[image: columns placement]

In black boxes there will be images. The white color represents the user screen view. I would like for those two horizontal boxes to fully fit to the screen edges.

```html
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300&text=1" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300&text=2" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <!-- make it span to the right edge of the screen on resolution >= medium -->
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300&text=3" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <!-- make it span to the left edge of the screen on resolution >= medium -->
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300&text=4" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300&text=5" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300&text=6" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300&text=7" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300&text=8" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300&text=9" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">some more content that is in container class, the total width of those three images above should be equal to this container so it fits nicely</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I give you the basic grid with elements that I want to see based on user screen size.

Any help with this would be great.

BTW: this need to be in the `container` because there will be content above and below those images and it needs to be somehow aligned to be consistent.

Comment: if i understood correct, why dont you use "col-md-offset-x" class?

Comment: I need to edit my question because I forgot to add one thing that this need to be in `container`. I want this to be aligned with the content above and below.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry this is not what i want to achieve. Please take a look at the screen and description. If something is not clear to you please ask me and I will tell you.

Comment: this is how it looks https://jsfiddle.net/yuyokk/2uohkv8c/ similar to yours but whit bigger paddings :)

Comment: I need those boxes to be in `container` class so they are aligned to any content that is before or after them - you did this part right but the main problem is that I want those two horizontal boxes to fit screen edges of browser. The white background is user browser screen, boxes are in `container` and basically what I want to do is to position them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `col-md-offset-x` class to achieve the gabs. For example a row with a gab at the beginning:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300/" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300/" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300/" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x300/" alt="" />
</div>
```

Note that you created a grid with 5 'places'. This is not possible in standard bootstrap, as bootstrap's grid is based upon 12 'places' (12 modulo 5 = 2).

Comment: The graphic designer made this 5 column design and I need to do as he instructed me. Sorry but your answer is not valid with my question.

Comment: That was just a note. My real answer is of course that you should use the `col-md-offset-x` class.

Comment: So you suggest using `container-fluid` - ok this will do I know but how will i align those images with content that is in `container`? Take a look at the image that I posted in my question. You see that in the end there are 3 equal boxes. Their total width should be equal to `container` with some content below that is not on the screen unfortunately.

Comment: I made a small update to the code that I've provided. Please run the code snippet and take a look. You have everything in the containers and i want only two of the images on the screenshot to be positioned somehow to the left and right edges of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only way to acheive this is with nesting and column offsets. Also, you have to use `container-fluid` if you want to fill the entire screen width. The use the grid columns to limit the width of the 3rd row. You're basically turning the 12 column grid into a 10 column grid.

http://codeply.com/go/k8LNUgjaa0

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-9">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any other solution for doing something similar? Btw something is broken. When you go full screen you have scrollers at the bottom - they probably shouldn't be there - right?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use customized column like below

```
<style>
    .col-md-offset-sp  { margin-left:20% }
    @media (min-width:992px) { .col-md-sp { position:relative;min-height:1px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;float:left; width: 20%; }}
    @media (min-width:992px) { .col-md-2sp { position:relative;min-height:1px;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;float:left; width: 40%; }}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-sp col-md-offset-sp"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-sp"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-2sp"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" /></div>

        <div class="col-md-2sp"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-sp"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-sp"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" /></div>

        <div class="col-md-sp col-md-offset-sp"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-sp"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-sp"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here col-md-sp and col-md-2sp take care of 5 column layout (width 20% & 40%). While col-md-offset-sp take care of margin for 5 column layout (margin-left 20%).

Note : other rules are just copied from bootstrap.css file